# Chrome or firefox don't trust gmail

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, firefox, gmail

On my laptop in Chrome v 16.0.912.63 m I keep getting the following screen whenever I try to go to gmail:

[image: chrome]

In firefox, I get a similar message but it allows me to add a security exception and go on.  This laptop has had some virus issues, but mbam has been run several times and I don't seem to have any other issues besides this one.  I'm also using a newly created profile.  Also, my laptop is the only one having issues on my network, everything else is working fine.

So, what could be causing this issue?

Comment: What is your date and time set to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [https: firefox and chrome say gmail's certificate is expired](http://superuser.com/questions/73864/https-firefox-and-chrome-say-gmails-certificate-is-expired)

Comment: @soandos: Not the same issue. yes it is set correctly – flybywire Nov 22 '09 at 15:12

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check your clock - i'd guess that its set to the wrong time, date or year, and as such your browsers believe the certs have expired

Comment: huh, weird.  fixing it worked!

Comment: Its happened to me before. I'd also suggest removing the battery and unplugging the laptop, and leaving for a while, then rebooting. If the time is wrong again, you will need to change your cmos battery